# Jquery progress bar for input 'file' on the client side (no backend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I want to add progressbar to `input[type=file]` upload. My problem is that all solutions i've found depend on `submit` btn and backend stuff with php. 


When user click `input[type=file]` and choose file - it gets uploaded to his browser, right? And only after he click `submit` it will be sent to server. 


**Is it possible to add progress bar that will not depend on `submit` btn and inform user about client side upload only?**

Comment: `When user click input[type=file] and choose file - it gets uploaded to his browser, right?` It doesn't get 'uploaded' to the local browser as the file is instantly accessible. Any progress bar at the point is redundant.